# What's the exact cause of Annie's issues with Eglamore?

Tags: gunnerkrigg-court

According to a Q&A on Tom Siddell's formspring -

> Is Annie's problem with Eglamore purely because of how he treated Reynardine, or is there more to it? It seems like she was already uncomfortable with him at the science fair, after he'd saved her but before she found out Reynardine was still alive.
>   **There's more to it than that.**

Has there been any information (interviews/twitter/formspring stuff said by Tom included) on what exactly there is to that? ('that' being Annie's problem with Eglamore)

Or, what ***is*** Annie's problem with Eglamore, exactly?

Comment: You mean apart from the fact that he was schtupping her mother?

Comment: @Richard Wait, do we have any proof Elgamore was? I had thought it was an unrequited crush.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees - It's not made clear, but he still carries a keepsake of their relationship more than a decade later.

Comment: Snape syndrome. It's not required for them to have ever had meaningful contact in order for him to be obsessed with her.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees I thought it was pretty clear they were in a relationship - the 'triple date' where Carver was supposed to ask out Brinnie, the flashback with Anya and Surma where Surma is missing James with very bf/gf type dialogue? and a few more instances I've seen around

Comment: @Richard If that's the only reason, shouldn't she also have issues with Reynardine? Seems weird from that angle, let alone the fact that 'oh this guy went out with my mom' => 'must dislike' doesn't seem very Antimony-ish.

Comment: But if they were in a relationship, why did Surma get herself knocked up by someone else? I didn't get that part.

Comment: @MrLister ?!!! They could have broken up and Surma gets together with Anthony? Like, is breaking up with people not something that happens in GC? I didn't get this comment...

Comment: @Shisa Sorry, I can't seem to find the reference right now, but I had a feeling that James and Surma never stopped being in love.